# How to send email after 1 month with php

Tags: php, email

In my web-application, i want to create a some-type of calendar plus reminder. For example, i need to create task and i want to receive a e-mail notification after 1 month.

How to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a cron job run every hour or so that finds all messages that haven't been delivered that were created a month ago.

Comment: Specifically the cronjob should run often enough that all notifications will arrive on-time. For example, if users can schedule notifications at 15 minute intervals, the cronjob should run every 15 minutes.

Comment: How can i activate this cron?

Comment: It should be already active on your system. Please read man cron or search Google to find out what cron is.